# Stack for bytes coming from different object/primitives

Tags: java

For my lab assignment we must do a simple virtual machine to run some basic instructions. The assignment document recommends and gives partial implementation in C... yet I want in Java.

For java the teacher recommended I use Java Nio ByteBuffer. Yet ByteBuffer does not behave as a stack.

Further complication is that I have no idea how to put in the stack the address of a jmp virtual instruction. I am thinking of serializing an instance of the Instr class and add those bytes to the stack but I fear that may be to many bytes for the stack.

My class for representing a virtual instruction:

```
public class Instr {

protected Instr(Opcode opcode2) {
    opcode = opcode2;
}

public enum Opcode {
    ADD_C, ADD_I, ADD_D, AND_A, AND_C, AND_I, AND_D, CALL, CALLEXT, CAST_C_D, CAST_C_I, CAST_D_C, CAST_D_I,
    CAST_I_C, CAST_I_D, DIC_C, DIC_I, DIV_D, DROP, ENTER, EQ_A, EQ_C, EQ_I, EQ_D, GREATER_C, GREATER_I, GREATER_D,
    GREATEREQ_C, GREATEREQ_I, GREATEREQ_D, HALT, INSERT, JF_A, JF_C, JF_I, JF_D, LESS_C, LESS_I, LESS_D, LESSEQ_C,
    LESSEQ_I, LESSEQ_D, LOAD, MUL_C, MUL_I, MUL_D, NEG_C, NEG_I, NEG_D, NOP, NOT_A, NOT_C, NOT_I, NOT_D, NOTEQ_A,
    NOTEQ_C, NOTEQ_I, NOTEQ_D, OFFSET, OR_A, OR_C, OR_I, OR_D, PUSHFPADDR, PUSHCT_A, PUSHCT_C, PUSHCT_I, PUSHCT_D,
    RET, STORE, SUB_C, SUB_I, SUB_D
}

public Opcode opcode;
public Register val1;
public Register val2;

private class Register {
    int i;
    double d;
    public Instr addr;
}
}
```

Any recommendations for building a stack that can put and pop objects/primitives?

This is my work so far:
https://github.com/EmanuelSadu/AtomC

This is the test code (in C) from the assignment document:

Example of what this VM must run like: 
In pagina „MV” sunt prezentate toate instructiunile masinii virtuale. Felul in care se folosesc acestea va fi detaliat in
laboratorul dedicat generarii codului. In acest laborator vom testa MV pe un cod scris direct. Un exemplu de cod care
implementeaza „v=3;do{put_i(v);v=v-1;}while(v);” este:

```
void mvTest()
{
Instr *L1;
int *v=allocGlobal(sizeof(long int));
addInstrA(O_PUSHCT_A,v);
addInstrI(O_PUSHCT_I,3);
addInstrI(O_STORE,sizeof(long int));
L1=addInstrA(O_PUSHCT_A,v);
addInstrI(O_LOAD,sizeof(long int));
addInstrA(O_CALLEXT,requireSymbol(&symbols,"put_i")->addr);
addInstrA(O_PUSHCT_A,v);
addInstrA(O_PUSHCT_A,v);
addInstrI(O_LOAD,sizeof(long int));
addInstrI(O_PUSHCT_I,1);
addInstr(O_SUB_I);
addInstrI(O_STORE,sizeof(long int));
addInstrA(O_PUSHCT_A,v);
addInstrI(O_LOAD,sizeof(long int));
addInstrA(O_JT_I,L1);
addInstr(O_HALT);
}
```

Comment: Assuming it is off limits to use [java.util.Stack](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Stack.html), you could instead implement a stack using an array. You need a pointer to the top of the stack – just an array index that you increment / decrement – and items that you store in the array. Note that it isn't necessary to physically _remove_ an item from your stack – you can safely leave an old entry in the array as long as your "top" pointer is kept up-to-date. Here's an explanation of implementing a stack with an array: https://www.cs.bu.edu/teaching/c/stack/array/

Comment: I considered using jav.util.Stack for this. I already used it to help do  the syntactic analysis of dummy C code.
The issue is that I need to put into the stack integers, double and *adress. Integers and double are clear since I just call the pop and push methods until all bytes of the primitive is consumed. Yet adress is a reference to another Instr object... How do I put into a stack this ?

Comment: A reference in Java is `Instr instr` because Java is always pass by value. You need to use `Stack<Instr> stack` and when you do `stack.add(new Instr())` what you store is the reference to an `Instr` object.

Answer (score 2):

Stay away from Java built-in serialization, it's an old mechanism from early days of the platform and [error prone](https://github.com/rzwitserloot/lombok/wiki/WHY-NOT:-serialVersionUID). You will be better to write your own simple format for this assignment.

You can write your own `Stack` class which is backed by a `ByteBuffer`, for example:

```
public class Stack {
  private final ByteBuffer buf;

  public Stack(int capacity) {
    buf = ByteBuffer.allocate(capacity);
  }

  public void push(byte b) {
    buf.put(b);
  }

  public byte pop() {
    if (buf.position() == 0) {
      throw new NoSuchElementException();
    }
    buf.position(buf.position() - 1);
    return buf.get(buf.position());
  }

}
```

Comment: This is something I also thought of. And in can be adapted to handle int and double properly. 
Yet I also need it to pop and push an *address. And I have no ideea how to add an adress into this. C would have been nice since I put a pointer into the stack... Yet I already done more than halph the work in java.

Comment: An address is just a number. Think what is the maximum size of your address, select a corresponding primitive e.g. `int` and use related methods e.g. `ByteBuffer.putInt()` and `getInt()`.

Comment: Not fessible...

I put into the initial message some extra explications.

Answer (score 0):

In the end I figured it out.
I thank @Karol Dowbecki the most for opening my eyes... Yes an addres is just a number. Now it makes sense.

I will soon push a full solution here:
https://github.com/EmanuelSadu/AtomC